# Customizing frequency tables and regression model outputs in r

Tags: r

I'm working to figure out how to make custom frequency tables. Most of the journals my group publishes in require odd formats for tables compared to how most R packages produce them. While I don't think this format is particularly useful to understand what happened this is what they usually look like

[image]

I know of `sjplot` and `stargazer` but I can't find code that can be adapted to this sort of format

I made an example dataframe in case this is useful

```
structure(list(gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), age = c(12, 65, 43, 22), treatment = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("control", "treatment"), class = "factor"), 
    hypertension = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Regarding the p values sometimes the DV will be the variable on the left hand side and other times it will be about predicting the treatment vs control condition (again, I don't believe this format is useful, but it is required). As such, the p value must sometimes be calculated by different statistical models. There is no clarification for what type of models are used for each variable in the table (logistic regression or mann whitney u for example). Color is not required at all. I'm just looking for something that generally looks like this and could be generated with code instead of manually writing in the output of multiple `glm` and `table` functions

Close approximations of this sort of table with succinct code would be preferred over more complex code. If the code is a little complex would greatly appreciate explanations of certain pieces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the package you're looking for is `tableone` (https://github.com/kaz-yos/tableone)

```
library(tableone)

sample_df <- structure(list(gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), age = c(12, 65, 43, 22), treatment = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("control", "treatment"), class = "factor"), 
    hypertension = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

vars <- names(sample_df)

tableOne <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, 
                           strata = c("treatment"), 
                           data = sample_df, 
                           factorVars = c("gender","hypertension","diabetes"))

print(tableOne)
#>                            Stratified by treatment
#>                             control       treatment      p      test
#>   n                             2             2                     
#>   gender = male (%)             0 (0.0)       2 (100.0)   0.317     
#>   age (mean (SD))           43.50 (30.41) 27.50 (21.92)   0.607     
#>   treatment = treatment (%)     0 (0.0)       2 (100.0)   0.317     
#>   hypertension = Yes (%)        0 (0.0)       2 (100.0)   0.317     
#>   diabetes = Yes (%)            0 (0.0)       2 (100.0)   0.317

Created on 2019-12-24 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

You can adjust what test performs the p-value check by declaring variables as normal or non-normal. It's pretty well documented in the vignette.

Comment: Excellent! Is there a way to export the table to word or latex?

Comment: Also, one other important thing is I'm sometimes looking to be able to *predict* the stratified variable by having the variables on the left be predictors of the stratified variable in a logistic regression model. Is this possible?

Comment: I've never found a good way to create pretty latex tables from this output, but I do like the package author suggests by using `print` on the table object with arguments `quote = TRUE` and `noSpaces = TRUE`. Then you can copy and paste into excel or word. Alternatively you can save as a csv file and import into excel and then use the excel object in word. If you like the answer please accept it by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: For your second question, I usually present logistic regression model outputs separately in a forest plot with `forestmodel` since it makes it easier to interpret visually.