# Convert table to more html or csv table in r

Tags: r, html-table

Follow up from previous post [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59473156/customizing-frequency-tables-and-regression-model-outputs-in-r/59473459?noredirect=1#comment105155616_59473459). I have an output from the tableone package created by this code

```
require(tableone)

sample_df <- structure(list(gender = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("female", 
"male"), class = "factor"), age = c(12, 65, 43, 22), treatment = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("control", "treatment"), class = "factor"), 
    hypertension = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", 
    "Yes"), class = "factor"), diabetes = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))

vars <- names(sample_df)

tableOne <- CreateTableOne(vars = vars, 
                           strata = c("treatment"), 
                           data = sample_df, 
                           factorVars = c("gender","hypertension","diabetes"))
```

Is there anyway to convert this to an html table that can be exported as a nice word or csv file with the quality of tables from `stargazer` and the like?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a markdown file? It's extremely customizable and flexible with export formats but also pretty easy to work with off the bat.

edit: I have included a screenshot below for clarity. Please let me know if this is not what you are trying to accomplish.

[image: Markdown Example with Table]

Comment: What do you mean by "make a markdown file"? You mean redo the table in markdown? the goal is to use the package because it's flexible and easy to work with even when there are a large number of variables

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. Yeah this isn't a terrible option, but I'm aiming more towards the output looking nice like the `sjplot` package tables